# How to use ‘Rx Observable’ in angular2 to resolve double click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, buffer, rxjs

```
let button = document.querySelector('.mbtn');
let lab = document.querySelector('.mlab');

let clickStream = Observable.fromEvent(button,'click');

let doubleClickStream = clickStream 
        .buffer(()=> clickStream.throttle(250))
        .map(arr => arr.length)
        .filter(len => len === 2); 

doubleClickStream.subscribe(event =>{
        lab.textContent = 'double click';
}); 

    doubleClickStream.throttle(1000)
        .subscribe(suggestion =>{
            lab.textContent = '-';
        });
```

but this is error in my angular2 project, who can help me to resolve it,
this is error log ↓

> ERROR in
>   /Users/genilex3/Desktop/meager/angularRxjs/angularrxjs/src/app/app.component.ts
>   (58,15): Argument of type '() => any' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'Observable'.   Property '_isScalar' is missing in type
>   '() => any'.
>
> ERROR in
>   /Users/genilex3/Desktop/meager/angularRxjs/angularrxjs/src/app/app.component.ts
>   (58,41): Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type '(value: {}) => SubscribableOrPromise'.

Comment: .buffer(()=> clickStream.throttle(250)) should be .buffer(clickStream.throttle(250))

Comment: let doubleClickStream = clickStream 
      .buffer(clickStream.throttle(250))
      .map(arr => arr.length)
      .filter(len => len === 2);     ERROR in /Users/genilex3/Desktop/meager/angularRxjs/angularrxjs/src/app/app.component.ts (58,36): Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) => SubscribableOrPromise<number>'.

ERROR in /Users/genilex3/Desktop/meager/angularRxjs/angularrxjs/src/app/app.component.ts (66,33): Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: number) => SubscribableOrPromise<number>'.

Comment: try this .buffer(clickStream.throttleTime(250))

Comment: You used the observable with rxjs 4 API, and I guess you are actually using rxjs 5. Take a look at rxjs 5 API

Comment: ERROR in /Users/genilex3/Desktop/meager/angularRxjs/angularrxjs/src/app/app.component.ts (67,33): Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}[]) => SubscribableOrPromise<number>'.

Comment: i use rxjs version is 5.0.1 , but   rxjs 5 API is Can't double click?

Comment: It can :) but I guess you took a reference from rxjs 4 code. This might help you: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: thanks  i will try it   memeda

Comment: Have you tried using (dblclick) event instead?

Comment: let doubleClickStream = clickStream.bufferTime(250)
       .map(arr =>arr.length)
       .filter(len => len ===2);     So that we can realize double click, to use double click because i want to learn rxjs ,thanks for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `bufferTime` for your stream.

```
let doubleClickStream = clickStream 
      .bufferTime(250)
      .map(arr => arr.length)
      .filter(len => len === 2);
```

Here you could read more: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferTime

If you want to clear your value after 1000ms after it was set you should use `debounceTime` method.

```
doubleClickStream.debounceTime(1000)
    .subscribe(suggestion =>{
        lab.textContent = '-';
    });
```

Here you could read more about `debounceTime`: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime

Comment: If it works, you should accept this answer by ticking on the left. @Holmes

Comment: Thanks! However, is there a way to have the observable return the original MouseEvent rather than the number of clicks?

Comment: I think that method is hiding a small "bug" though. If you double click really fast, it will wait for the bufferTime to finish instead of emitting directly after the second click.